# Any way to customize the initialization of variables in the bc calculator?

Tags: bc, calculator

The bc calculator appears to assign uninitialized variables the value of zero. I would like to alter this behavior so that when bc encounters an uninitialized variable, it instead flags the expression as invalid. For example, in the following code,

```
echo "foo + bar" | bc -l
```

bc assigns the value 0 to foo and bar and returns "0". I would like it instead to return the empty string "" or in some other way indicate that "foo + bar" is an invalid expression. Is there a way to accomplish this in bc?

Comment: `bc -w` would flag mutli-character variable expressions. But I don't think that is what you want. Actually, what do you really need this for? I am a bit afraid for an XY-type of problem.

Comment: Please see my reply to Drav Sloan, which explains what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: No. It does not explain what you are trying to accomplish. Your goal is not to use `bc`. I suppose it is part of a bigger problem you are trying to solve, and I am afraid that you are on a wrong route. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem to see what my concern is.

Comment: My goal is to convert a mathematical expression of arbitrary complexity (as long as it's valid in, say, the bc calculator) to its decimal form with arbitrary precision. For example, I would like to convert "1*10^-900 + 1*10^-900" to "0.[...899 0's...]2". bc does this correctly, but if I enter a typo such as "1*10^-900 + q*10^-900", instead of flagging it as an invalid expression, bc returns "0.[...899 0's...]1" because it initializes "q" to 0.

Comment: And why do you want to use `bc` per se?

Comment: To convert a mathematical expression of arbitrary complexity to its decimal form with arbitrary precision.

Comment: Maybe I need to ask it more explicitly in order for you to see my point. Why do you roll out, e.g. `perl` or `expr` or whatever other tool may be useful? I would recommend to formulate your question in such a way that is open to alternative. Now you already scare away everyone unfamiliar with `bc`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26762/discussion-between-scolfax-and-bernhard).

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, barring a way to flag undeclared variables as invalid in bc, I came up with a workable solution in case it is of use to others. The expression to be executed by bc is first piped through a sed command, which strips any reserved bc words from the expression. Any remaining variable names are considered to be undeclared variables, and the entire expression is converted to a statement that will force an error when executed in bc (I chose '1/0', but any of a number of alternative error flags could be constructed.)

Generates a run-time "Divide by zero" error:

```
echo 'foo + bar' | sed -E '
    ## Save the original expression in the hold space
    h
    ## Recursively replace all bc reserved words with a unique token string (¦§§¦)
    :again
    s/auto|break|continue|define|else|for|halt|ibase|if|last|length|limits|obase|print|quit|read|return|scale|sqrt|warranty|while/¦§§¦/g
    s/(a|c|e|j|l|s)([(][^)]*[)])/¦§§¦\2/g
    t again
    ## If the expression contains any bc reserved words abutting one another, mark the expression as invalid, and skip to the end of the sed script
    /¦§§¦¦§§¦/s/^.+$/1\/0/
    t
    ## Replace all tokens with spaces
    s/¦§§¦/ /g
    ## If any variable names remain, treat them as undeclared variables, mark the expression as invalid, and skip to the end of the sed script
    ## Prior to doing this, reset the t command so that it can recognize if a substitution takes place in the s command
    t reset
    :reset
    /[a-z][a-z0-9_]*/s/^.+$/1\/0/
    t
    ## If the expression does not have undeclared variable names, get the original expression from the hold space
    g
' | bc -l
```

Returns the correct answer = 246:

```
echo '123 + 123' | sed -E '
    ## Save the original expression in the hold space
    h
    ## Recursively replace all bc reserved words with a unique token string (¦§§¦)
    :again
    s/auto|break|continue|define|else|for|halt|ibase|if|last|length|limits|obase|print|quit|read|return|scale|sqrt|warranty|while/¦§§¦/g
    s/(a|c|e|j|l|s)([(][^)]*[)])/¦§§¦\2/g
    t again
    ## If the expression contains any bc reserved words abutting one another, mark the expression as invalid, and skip to the end of the sed script
    /¦§§¦¦§§¦/s/^.+$/1\/0/
    t
    ## Replace all tokens with spaces
    s/¦§§¦/ /g
    ## If any variable names remain, treat them as undeclared variables, mark the expression as invalid, and skip to the end of the sed script
    ## Prior to doing this, reset the t command so that it can recognize if a substitution takes place in the s command
    t reset
    :reset
    /[a-z][a-z0-9_]*/s/^.+$/1\/0/
    t
    ## If the expression does not have undeclared variable names, get the original expression from the hold space
    g
' | bc -l
```

Edit note:  This is a refinement of my original submission and is more accurate in detecting undeclared variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `expr` ?

```
$ expr foo + bar
expr: non-integer argument
$ expr 1 + 5
6
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is after... `echo "foo=1; bar=2; foo+bar" | expr` gives `expr: missing operand`. I don't think expr is a useful substitute here (where as ` echo "foo=1; bar=2; foo+bar" | bc -l` responds `3`). The OP want an error to be thrown when foo or bar is not declared (which `bc` usually sets to zero).

Comment: Drav Sloan, that is correct. I gave a simple example, but I'd like to send bc an arbitrarily complex expression and, as long as it's a valid bc expression, get the result from bc in decimal form. For example, `echo "1.2*10^3" | bc -l` returns "1200.0". I was hoping for bc to flag an invalid expression perhaps due to a typo such as `echo "1.2*10^w" | bc -l`, but instead it returns "1.2" because it initializes "w" to zero.